# CRM Reports SQL GUID

Tags: sql, crm, fetch, guid

I need to create a SQL report that filters based on the CRM user running the report. This is easily accomplished with Fetch utilizing;

```
<condition attribute="systemuserid" operator="eq-userid" />
```

But for this report i need SQL. When i try;

```
WHERE  (systemuserid = dbo.fn_FindUserGuid())
```

the returned user is the reporting server dbo.. Not the actual CRM user.

Is there away to get the user correctly from SQL or any way to combined both fetch and sql data sets in one report?

Answer (score 0):

WHERE (systemuserid = dbo.fn_FindUserGuid())

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/182619/454088